# How to disable system location alert in iOS simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios-simulator, cllocationmanager

I use KIF framework (http://github.com/kif-framework/KIF) with Xcode Continuous Integration Server for UI testing.

When XCode CI server start app in iOS Simulator system alert "Application would like to use your current location" appears.

I use this delegate

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didChangeAuthorizationStatus: (CLAuthorizationStatus)status
```

to get the notification that user allows to use location and I need it to keep like it is.

1. Is it possible to tap OK on this system alert with KIF ? I didn't found out the way.
2. Or how to allow application use location service in simulator without showing this alert ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this answer from the top KIF contributor](https://github.com/kif-framework/KIF/issues/149), dismissing system alerts automatically is impossible, and you should therefore mock (i.e. provide a substitute for) the location service so that you can test your code without running into the alert.

Comment: Caleb, It might work, but the problem is that location service starts before KIF method -beforeAll invoked.
So it's too late to mock.